# Is there an algorithm to replace apostrophes (') with their slanted varients (’ and ‘) in an english phrase?

Tags: string, quotes, double-quotes

We're given an arbitrary English phrase containing apostrophes `'` (`U+0027`) and quotation marks `"` (`U+0022`). Is there an algorithm that appropriately replaces these characters with their slanted variants?

- Apostrophes `'` would become:

  - Right single quotation mark `’` (`U+2019`) or
  - Left single quotation mark `‘` (`U+2018`)
- Quotation marks `"` would become:

  - Left double quotation marks `“` (`U+201C`) or
  - Right double quotation marks `”` (`U+201D`)

We can guarantee that inputs are grammatically correct English sentences.

Examples:

- `I'm doing great!` becomes `I’m doing great!`
- `"Aren't you a little short?"` becomes `“Aren’t you a little short?”`
- `"When you said 'Commas don't matter,' I died a little inside."` becomes `“When you said ‘Commas don’t matter,’ I died a little inside.”`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I was looking for smart quotes.

- http://www.pensee.com/dunham/smartQuotes.html
- https://smartquotes.js.org/